# Include the question's tags in the news feed

Tags: feature-request, tags, feed

When I get a new article in a news feed, I'd like to quickly know if it makes sense for me to look into the details or not. One such criterion is Delphi version, which should be specifically tagged by the poster.

If the news feed of new questions also contained the tag list, it would be much more useful to me, and maybe would lessen the load of your server: feed readers could ignore some questions instead of going WWW and loading a full-blown page.